# Trim new line character at end of jtl file saved from JMeter command line

Tags: jmeter

On `Ubuntu`, inside of a bash script, this ran ( along with some other commands ):

```
sudo jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l /home/ubuntu/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/results.jtl
```

When I do a "ls", I see this file with a question mark in the filename for some reason `results.jtl?`. I believe this is because there is a new line at the end of the file after the last line of the `.jtl`:

"
"

That question mark character in the file name is causing me problems. If I open the file with nano, manually delete the newline out of the file and save the file as `results.jtl`, then I can use the `.jtl` file like normal.

How can I get `JMeter` to save the `.jtl` without adding that newline to the end of the `.jtl`?

If that is not possible, how can I fix this? I would like to avoid using code to read the file and make adjustments. I would think there should be a more straightforward answer to this.

I also tried to open some of my other scripts involved and remove any white-space or new lines at the end of those scripts. This has not helped either, though. I was thinking about why the "?" would be in the file name, to begin with, and trying any solutions.

Furthermore, if I deleted the "results.jtl?" file and ran the `JMeter` command on the command line, not inside a bash script file, then `JMeter` did not save it with the ? in the file name. So, it's only when the bash script is run that the ? is in the file name.

Comment: did you create your shell script file on linux, or mac/windows? Open it in `vm` or `vim` - you should be able to see what kind of character is that. Could be anything really - like a `FF` code for international character, not only new line. Another option is to just retype the command using linux editor in an empty file